# Phonegap build failed : Multiple dex files

Tags: android, cordova

I try to implement the Google+ login in my app with this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Sadly, this plugin is not working for me. When I install the plugin and I run the command "phonegap build android" it shows me a build failed error message. Here is a pastebin of it: http://pastebin.com/hSuKsNEs

I am searching the whole day to fix this problem but I can't find the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below code in your gradle file

`configurations {
       all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' 
   }`